# Which design pattern is used to give a class extra properties?

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns

When you have a `TableLayoutPanel` on your `Form` and you drag a `Label` into a cell, a few properties are available on the `Label` control. I think the same construction is used when you drag a `Tooltip` control on the form.

I'd like to know which design pattern is used to achieve this. Is this the decorator pattern?

Comment: Do you mean the properties that you see **only** if the label in TableLayoutPanel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing are called [Extender Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171835.aspx).

> For example, when a ToolTip component is added to a form, it provides
>   a property called ToolTip to each control on that form. The ToolTip
>   property then appears in any attached PropertyGrid control.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171836.aspx

I can't think of a well-known pattern that describes how they work, exactly, but the mechanism is simple.

You must implement [`IExtenderProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider.aspx).  The WinForms Designer will call `CanExtend` for each other control on the surface, and your extender can specify if it provides additional attributes for each control.

```
public interface IExtenderProvider {
    bool CanExtend(object extendee);
}
```

The actual attributes that other controls will be extended are declared using the [`ProvidePropertyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.providepropertyattribute.aspx) and [a method to provide the value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229066.aspx).

Comment: Seems kind of WPF Attached Properties implementation for design time in WinForms.

Comment: the "pattern" is a Polymorphism :)

Comment: @Tigran: I don't think I'd say that, as nowhere are you subclassing and overriding an implementation.  It maybe has a hint of visitor, by calling `CanExtend` against each control - but then it's not really visitor since it relies on type checking in the `CanExtend` method.  It's also an unknown internal mechanism how the extended attributes are actually exposed in the Property Grid in the designer (there's actually an old MSDN article that goes over it in detail somwhere).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not achieved through a design pattern. These properties are simply the public properties exposed by the control, these properties are added to the control via inheritence, i.e. they sub-class `Control`. The visual studio designer inspects the class which implements these controls to determine the properties they expose, then provides you with a UI for setting them.